# How to I reveal a hidden image using core graphics by drawing with finger?

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, touch-event

I have a custom UIView where I handle touch events from the user. This view contains a UIImageView where I show a hidden image. I want to use touch events from the user to slowly reveal the hidden image. I think core graphics need to be used, but I'm not sure how to do that. How can this be achieved?

What I have now:

```
public class customTouchView: UIView {
    
    var overlayImageView = UIImageView()
    
    override open func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        overlayImageView.frame = rect
    }
    
    func drawAt(_ point: CGPoint) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(overlayImageView.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
        overlayImageView.image?.draw(in: overlayImageView.bounds)
        
        //Draw here, need to somehow reveal the image
        
        
        overlayImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    }
    
    init(image: UIImage) {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        //Just adding overlayImageView as a subview, setting my image and alpha to 0.5. The image should be hidden at the beginning and touch events that draw over the image should reveal the image. 
        addSubview(overlayImageView)
        overlayImageView.image = image
        overlayImageView.alpha = 0.5
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    public override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
        let point = touch.location(in: self)
        drawAt(point)
    }
    
    public override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
        let point = touch.location(in: self)
        drawAt(point)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily by using a `CAShapeLayer` as a mask layer...

The portions of the mask that are clear (alpha = 0) will **not** show through, while the portions that are not clear (alpha = 1) **will** show through.

Use the touches to add points and lines to a `UIBezierPath` that will be used as the `.path` of the shape layer. As you "draw" the path will "reveal" the underlying image.

Here's a simple example...

A "Reveal Image View" (`UIImageView` subclass):

```
class RevealImageView: UIImageView {
    
    private var maskPath = UIBezierPath()
    private var maskLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        // default is false for UIImageView
        isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        // we only want to stroke the path, not fill it
        maskLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        // any color will work, as the mask uses the alpha value
        maskLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        // adjust drawing-line-width as desired
        maskLayer.lineWidth = 48
        maskLayer.lineCap = .round
        maskLayer.lineJoin = .round
        // set the mask layer
        layer.mask = maskLayer
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        maskLayer.frame = bounds
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
        let currentPoint = touch.location(in: self)
        maskPath.move(to: currentPoint)
    }
    
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
        let currentPoint = touch.location(in: self)
        // add line to on maskPath
        maskPath.addLine(to: currentPoint)
        // update the mask layer path
        maskLayer.path = maskPath.cgPath
    }
    
}
```

and an example view controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let myRevealView = RevealImageView(frame: .zero)
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        guard let img = UIImage(named: "sampleImage") else {
            fatalError("Could not load image!!!!")
        }
        myRevealView.image = img
        
        // a view to show the frame for the Reveal Image view
        //  so we know where we can "draw"
        let frameView = UIView()
        frameView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        frameView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        
        frameView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        myRevealView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        view.addSubview(frameView)
        view.addSubview(myRevealView)

        // respect safe area
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // 300 x 300 (1:1 ratio)
            myRevealView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300.0),
            myRevealView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myRevealView.widthAnchor),
            // centered in view
            myRevealView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            myRevealView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
            
            // constrain the frame view 2-pts larger
            frameView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myRevealView.widthAnchor, constant: 2.0),
            frameView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: frameView.widthAnchor),
            // center it
            frameView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myRevealView.centerXAnchor),
            frameView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myRevealView.centerYAnchor),

        ])
        
    }
}
```

Using this as my "sampleImage":

[image]

it looks like this after "drawing" a bit:

[image]