# How to erase a custom shape ( not A rectangle ) in CGContext

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

I'm trying to achieve that effect like **scratch lottery** in iOS. The basic effect is achieved by using `clear(_rect: CGRect)`, but how to erase a **custom shape** rather than a rectangle?
Here is my code

```
class ImageMaskView: UIView {
    var image  = UIImage(named: "maskL")
    
    var line = [CGPoint ]()

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {return}
        
        image?.draw(at: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 300))
        
//     erase
            line.forEach { (position) in
//                print(position)
                let rect = CGRect(x: position.x,y:position.y,width:50,height:50)
                    context.clear(rect)
            }
    }
        
        
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
            guard let position = touches.first?.location(in: nil) else{return }
            print(position)
            line.append(position)
            setNeedsDisplay()

        }
}
```

Maybe I can build a custom function `clear`? Anyway, I would appreciate it if you can give me some advice

Comment: Take a look at this Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66202189/how-to-i-reveal-a-hidden-image-using-core-graphics-by-drawing-with-finger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried UIBezierPath? You definitely can use UIBezierPath to build the custom shape. But I'm not 100% sure how to clear instead of draw this path in context. Try something like this:

```
let starPath: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath()
starPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 45.25, y: 0))
starPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 61.13, y: 23))
starPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 88.29, y: 30.75))
starPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 70.95, y: 52.71))
starPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 71.85, y: 80.5))
starPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 45.25, y: 71.07))
starPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 18.65, y: 80.5))
starPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 19.55, y: 52.71))
starPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 2.21,  y: 0.75))
starPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 29.37, y: 23))
starPath.close();
context.setBlendMode(.destinationOut)
context.setFillColor(UIColor.clear.cgColor)
starPath.fill()
```

Also, don't forget to set opaque of your view to false.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that `UIBezierPath()` can create a custom shape. But when I invoke `context.fill`, it won't erase this area(`context.fill()` seems not to mean redrawing the shape area). Anyway thanks for HELP